# how to limit the json fields while getting response in spring rest

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest

```
this the code:

@RequestMapping(value="/find/city={city}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Master_City> getCity(@PathVariable String city)
 {
    return City_Repository.findByCityLikeIgnoreCase(city);
 }
```

All the JSON Fields are showing.I required only 2 Fields.

Comment: while in response : {
    "id": "57731797c0d995a32aa15623",
    "indexid": 65,
    "city": "Barcelona",
    "country": {
      "id": "576ced3ac0d911e15272d3f3",
      "indexid": 136,
      "country": "Spain",
      "foundin": "{ \"expedia\" : 1 , \"hpo\" : 1}",
      "code": "{ \"expedia\" : 166}"
    }

Comment: Your function is written to return the entire object. Instead of returning City_Repository, make something like an array inside the function, push the fields you need from City_Repository into the array, and then return the array instead of the entire City_Repository object.

Comment: If you're using Jackson then `@JsonIgnoreProperties` might help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

Just add @JsonIgnore annotation to field's getter you don't want to send
Example:

```
class MasterCity{
 private String contact;
  private String address;
     public String getContact() {
    return contact;
}

public void setContact(String contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}
@JsonIgnore
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
}


@RequestMapping(value="/find/city={city}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Master_City> getCity(@PathVariable String city)
 {
    return City_Repository.findByCityLikeIgnoreCase(city);
 }
```

Now it'll ignore the address